# How to prove every subgroup $K$ of $ G$ is a normal subgroup of $N_G(K)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

That is, how to prove
$N_{N_G(K)}(K)=N_G(K)$?

For $K\leq N_G(K)$.

Comment: Hm. This certainly resembles the double-centraliser theorem in the theory of division algebras.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition,
$$N_G(K)=\{g\in G\mid gKg^{-1}=K\}.$$
(which, by the way, shows that $K\subseteq N_G(K)$ for any subgroup $K$ of $G$).